# Mocking a service in Typscript with Jest and verifying the parameters

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

The output of a ES6 class is a call to a service class 'addRowStandalone'. Checking how this mocked service was called is proving to be a challenge. Typesript.

The class is minimally

```
export class WinnerCsvService {
   saveService: WinnerSaveService;

   constructor() {
     this.saveService = new WinnerSaveService();
   }
   async readFile() {
      const winner = buildWinner();
      await this.saveService.addRowStandalone(winner);
   }
}
```

WinnerSaveService is mocked in `__mocks__`

```
export class WinnerSaveService {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Mock winner save service was called");
  }
  addRow() {
    console.log("Mock add row was called");
  }
  addRowStandalone() {
    console.log("Mock addRowStandalone was calledx");
  }
}
```

The test case

```
import 'jest'
import {mocked} from 'ts-jest/utils';
import {WinnerSaveService} from "../winner-save.service";
jest.mock('../winner-save.service')

describe('csv', () => {
  const s3Mock = mockClient(S3Client);

  beforeEach(() => {
    s3Mock.reset()
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('Large winner', async () => {
    const winnerCsvService = new WinnerCsvService();
    await winnerCsvService.readFile();
    // Assertions
  });
});
```

The base test runs with console output from the mocked save service, showing that the mock is being called

```
console.log
Mock winner save service was called
```

I'm not so sure about *addRowStandalone*. The debugger says it is being called, without the console output (event triggers may not be getting caught).

Changing the 'Assertions' section

```
expect(WinnerSaveService.constructor).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
```

Gives

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Likewise all of the following

```
expect(WinnerSaveService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
expect(WinnerSaveService.addRowStandalone).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
expect(winnerCsvService.saveService.addRowStandalone).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
expect(winnerCsvService.saveService.addRowStandalone).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a');
```

And

```
const aWinner = (winnerCsvService.saveService.addRowStandalone as jest.Mock)
expect(aWinner).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
```

The goal is to check the parameters

> expect(winnerCsvService.saveService.addRowStandalone).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a');

Additionally, I have *jest.config.js* with ts-jest

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
```

And some packages

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
   "jest": "^28.1.3",
   "ts-jest": "^28.0.7",
```

Comment: Your `WinnerSaveService` test double doesn't support `toHaveBeenCalled...` because its methods aren't actually Jest mocks/spies. Every time you new it up you get a separate instance anyway. Note also your `WinnerCsvService` isn't very testable because it instantiates its own collaborators; `constructor(private saveService: WinnerSaveService) {` would be better encapsulation (not publicly exposing service) and more testable (inverting the dependency).

Comment: Thank you. In my opinion the most intelligent advice I've had on this platform.